# What are "Community Wiki" posts good for nowadays?

Tags: discussion, edits, community-wiki

In light of a recent blog entry by Grace Note, [The Future of Community Wiki](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/), I think we should reevaluate the old SO FAQ entry regarding CW: [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/133368)

In [the single answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741) to that question, the question ***Why have Community Wiki posts?*** is answered with some general blahblah that doesn't tell me anything, the question ***How do Community Wiki posts work?*** lists "some of the key features", among which the "much lower reputation" needed for editing is listed as a prime one.

Me thinks this needs a general renovation. Any thoughts?

Comment: I've added a link to Grace Note's blog post at the top of the answer you cited.  Does that suffice?

Comment: @Robert: I don't think this suffices. This FAQ thing is a Q&A game. People go to that question when they have a question ("What is CW?") and search for an answer. The answer wasn't very helpful to begin with, my critique above still stands after your edit. Adding a link to a lengthy blog posting (not exactly a typical answer format at the best of times) which goes to great length to explain a likely future of a feature, thereby basically requiring knowledge of its past in order to make sense, doesn't really get to the point to answer the question.

Comment: What is needed instead is a straightforward answer explaining what CW is (and "Community Wiki posts help enhance the wiki aspect of the site" does ___not___ explain what it is at all), when it is useful, how it is applied, and by whom. Having another answer explaining its past might be helpful, too.

Comment: CW resists attempts to define it in this way, which is why the FAQ post is technical in nature; it describes *what* CW is, but not *why* it exists, because the *why* defies explanation; the *why* has a long and colorful history that is still evolving.

Comment: The basic idea behind CW is to "give the post to the community" by lowering the editing requirements and waiving reputation. *That's all CW really is.* In the past, it has been co-opted and misused by the community for other purposes, but it is really no more than that.

Comment: @Robert: For one, I'd differentiate between the historical development of the goal and the current goal. And, frankly, if the current goal cannot be stated in one or two sentences, then there might be a problem with it. But also, I know what the original intent of CW was, but I already said (and the blog agrees with me) that the historical intent isn't needed anymore, because users can edit now without having 100rep. That still leaves the question of what it is used for today. Which still isn't answered.

Comment: I'm not sure there *is* a purpose in Community Wiki anymore. It's primary purpose has always been to lower the editing threshold, but since the "suggested edits" feature allows *anyone* (including anonymous users) to contribute edits, I think it will be very rare indeed that CW is necessary.

Comment: @Cody: As I see it, the only place CW still has is preventing the original provider of an answer (or question) from getting rep for it. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but if I'm right, this is what it ought to say on the package.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of offtopic, but let's see when we actually set a community wiki. I marked a question as a community wiki:

- When I knew the answer (read about this in a blog, or just searched in Google, or just had access to working code, but the code was not mine), but I didn't have any experience/expertise in the field to provide any additional information or to answer potential questions/resolve issues. So I posted the raw answer and invited the community to help explain.
- When someone else edited my post with a great explanation about what I've wrote - since the explanation is actually more valuable that the piece of code (I'm a Stack Overflow user) - I don't feel right "owning" the post and gathering any upvotes
- For a post that will end up with a list in it, so I want people to be able to edit that list.

Any others? ;)

Comment: The first two you mention are when you would be ashamed to earn rep from someone else's work. Fine, that's really noble. The last one isn't necessary anymore, because you don't need much rep anymore to edit someone else's answers, you only need others to approve your edit. (Of course, with list answers that might still leaves the other reasons, but this one's out.)

Answer (score 1):

One of the trends happening on SE sites is for the FAQ questions to have just one answer, there is no official standing on this, but the mods have been incrementally making it so.  In that case it would be good for the 'canonical' answer to be Community Wiki, i.e. owned by the Community.

Comment: Are you referring to the red-tag faq questions here?

Comment: @Robert, yes, right now out of 126 [FAQ] questions, 40 have only one answer.

Comment: _Huh?_ That answer _is_ CW.

Comment: @sbi, Yes, I know, and I'm saying that's one purpose for CW.

Comment: @Lance: But it isn't. Suggested edits have taken over this functionality.

Comment: @sbi, I think the only point I was making was that the sole FAQ answer should be community-owned, not any one individuals answer, since many people will be editing it over time.

Comment: @Lance: Fine. So one of the reasons CW exists is for the FAQ which explains why it exists? That seems a...um, _very tangential point_.

Answer (score 0):

There is a functional difference between Community Wiki and Suggested Edits.

Suggested Edits allow anyone to make an edit, but it then has to go *through an approval process* if their rep is under the editing privilege level.

Community Wiki allows anyone with 100 rep to make an edit *without approval*.

I'm not saying that CW is a good thing for this reason, since maybe the approval process for any low-rep users is what Stack Exchange wants, but the clarification was needed.

Comment: I think the _main_ difference between the two is that CW prevents the original author from getting any rep.

Comment: @sbi, Please understand that is only a side-effect of the Community owning the post, and not the intended purpose.  Also remember that badges are still earned on CW posts.

Comment: It _used to be_ a side-effect. Now it is the main feature of CW. There's no significant difference between suggested edits and CW. (And what difference there is is usually considered an advantage.) And why would questions that are popular, gain more than a dozen answers (and thus have their votes sky-rock) be turned CW, if not to prevent a flaw in the voting system (votes correlate to popularity more than to quality) from wreaking to much havoc by preventing users from harvesting rep? And what other reason is there to keep CW nowadays?